# Run code after all .each()-originating AJAX requests have finished

Tags: jquery, variables, global

I want to process the results after all the element's AJAX requests are processed. However, my `test` variable is not alerting the correct value. How can I do this?

```
var test = 0;

$('#div :input').each(function() {
    var loadUrl = "path_to/ajax.php?label="+value;  
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: loadUrl,
        success: function(msg) {
            if(msg == 1) {
                test++;
            }
            else if(msg == 2) {
                test++;
            }
        }
    });                     
});

alert(test);
```

Comment: That's because those AJAX calls are asynchronous, but the `alert()` runs immediately.

Comment: have you tried to put the `alert(test);` in the `success:`?

Comment: Yes but I want to process the result after all the elements are processed

Comment: Keep a counter of all the results like you do `test`, and when it equals your `$('#div :input').length`, run that code/function. Also, using [`$.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) instead of global variables is a better practice.

Answer (score 0):

When the `alert()` is reached the ajax call is not complete yet and the `success` callback has not yet been called. Therefore `test` still has its initial value.

Comment: I know that but I tried anything, any tips how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

As what you're trying to do is do something when all GET requests have been completed, you should track all of the requests and then do something.

Note, if you are attempting to contact a resource that may not return, you may want to put in a timeout check and/or use the [`complete`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events) handler instead, which will fire after all other handlers will, including if there's an error, timeout or whatnot (meaning, `success` may never run and your code may never be told to finish).

Important! Have either Chrome Console or Firebug in Firefox open to view the output.

```
<div id="div">
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
</div>

console.clear();
var c_inputs = 0;
var $div = $('#div');
var $inputs = $div.find(':input');
$div.data('data-inputs',$inputs.length);
$div.data('data-messages',0);
console.log('Number of inputs: ' + $div.data('data-inputs') + ' Number of messages: ' + $div.data('data-messages'));

$inputs.each(function() {
    var loadUrl = "#";  
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: loadUrl,
        success: function(msg) {
            var $div = $('#div');
            var count = parseInt($div.data('data-messages'));
            var inputs = parseInt($div.data('data-inputs'));
            count++;
            $div.data('data-messages',count);
            console.log('Current message count: ' + count + ' == Total Inputs: ' + inputs);
            if (count == inputs) {
                finishedInputs();
            }
        }
    });                     
});

function finishedInputs() {
    console.log('Finished! (' +
        $('#div').data('data-messages') +
        ' of ' +
        $('#div').data('data-inputs') +
        ')'
    );
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/msJgT/

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = 0;
var semaphore = 0;

$('#div :input').each(function() {
    var loadUrl = "path_to/ajax.php?label="+value;  
    semaphore++;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: loadUrl,
        success: function(msg) {
            if(msg == 1) {
                test++;
            }
            else if(msg == 2) {
                test++;
            }
        },
        complete: function() {
            semaphore--;
            if (semaphore == 0) { alert(test); }
        }
    });                     
});
```